# Как через hover обратиться не к соседнему и не родителю, а к вообще другому элементу

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как при такой вложенности при наводе на h2 c классом title изменять img? просто через `.title:hover .img` или `.title:hover~.img` не работает

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <h2 class="title"> </h2>
    <p class="text"> </p>
    <p class="text"> </p>
    <p class="text"> </p>
    <p class="text"> </p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img class="img">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Это невозможно сделать на чистом CSS, по причине того, что в CSS отсутствует селектор родительского элемента. Но можно с применением JS.

Comment: А как это сделать с помощью js?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как вариант можно сделать так: для каждого `h2` с помощью `parentNode` дойти до общего родителя, а затем в этом родителе отыскать парный `img`:

```js
var h2s = window.document.querySelectorAll(".title");
h2s.forEach(function(h2) {

  h2.addEventListener("mouseenter", function(event) {
    var img = this.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector(".img");
    if (img) {
      img.classList.add("active");
    }    
  });

  h2.addEventListener("mouseleave", function(event) {
    var img = this.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector(".img");
    if (img) {
      img.classList.remove("active");
    }    
  });
  
});
```

```css
.img.active {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <h2 class="title">Hover Me</h2>
    <p class="text">1</p>
    <p class="text">2</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/600/400" class="img">
  </div>
</div>
```